# QoS don't work with more than two instances

Tags: c, windows, qos

The QoS by Microsoft have a limitation for how many connections that can work?

I'm using the sample of Microsoft on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/Qos/Qos2/qossample.c)

What I'm doing here it's to compile. Run the program sending packets to any computer on my network with some bitrate. The `define` `BURSTS_PER_SECOND` it's setted to 1000 and the `DATAGRAM_SIZE` setted to 150 * 150

```
// Size of the data part of each datagram that is exchanged between the
// client and the server. This does not count the IP and UDP header.
#define DATAGRAM_SIZE       150 * 150

// Number of bursts we are aiming for per second
#define BURSTS_PER_SECOND   1
```

When I run one program, I can see:

```
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
```

As you can see, the bitrate it's always constant and the number of packets too. When I open the second instance sending the same data with same parameters, everything works fine.

But when I open one more, I can see:

```
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         0 |          0 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         0 |          0 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
         3 |     540000 |     N/A     |     N/A    |
```

Sometimes I get 3 packets sended in one second and other 0 packets. The burst time it's setted to 1 second but with 3 instances (three different processes) the time grows to 1500ms. And every new instance will make the problem more intensive. And when I close all instances letting just two or one, everything runs well as before.

My issue here is: Windows have some limitation with QoS? Why I can't open 3 instance of QoS? My network it's not busy (i'm sending small data).

I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: regarding: `#define BURSTS_PER_SECOND   1`  this does not match the text of your question that states 1000 bursts per second.

Comment: Your statement says the datagram size is 150x150.  (I.E. 22500 bytes per packet) 1) there is no guarantee that a datagram will ever be received.  2) Ethernet packets are (typically) broken into (approx) 1600 bytes each.  so several packets will be sent for each of the `send()` or `sendto()` or `write()` statements executed.  However, how are we to know what your code is actually doing when you haven't posted a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem so we can help you debug it.

Comment: regarding: `I'm doing something wrong?`  Perhaps the interface is being overloaded.  How can we tell when you have not provided the code?

Comment: @user3629249 the code is the same as Microsoft Sample (link on post). Sorry for my mismatch. The time to send it's 1000ms.  The main question is: my network can send 1Gbits normally with QoS without problems. But when I distribute on 3 QoS connections of 300Mbits, the problem occurs. Even with 1Mbits. Don't make sense. The amount of data is the same or less.

Comment: @user3629249 my real problem is using MPEGTS of LIBAV but with MS sample I can reproduce the same, descarting a problem with my QoS  control code. I can control the bitrate and I can keep stable with maximum of 2 QoS connections (128k per audio channel, 16 audio channels, with overhead of TransportStream). When I open one more, the problem occurs (the data it's not sended as before).